# React button radio this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, reactstrap

I have 2 component a parent component to manage the state and a lot of other things and a child component with some reactstrap buttons radio i'm trying to change the state onClick on the child buttons but I get the error: this.setState is not a function and i can't figure out what's wrong with my code =>

```
//Parent
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BtnRadio from './btnToggle';


class parent extends Component {

    state = {
        rSelected: true,
    }

    onRadioBtnClick(rSelected) {
        this.setState({ 
            rSelected:rSelected 
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (

            <div>
                <BtnToggle onRadioBtnClick={this.onRadioBtnClick} active={this.state.rSelected}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
};

export default AddAdmin;

//Chlid

import React from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'reactstrap';

const BtnRadio = (props) => {

    return (
        <ButtonGroup>
            <Button color="light" onClick={() => props.onRadioBtnClick(true)} active={props.active === true}>Enable</Button>
            <Button color="light" onClick={() => props.onRadioBtnClick(false)} active={props.active === false}>Disabled</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>     
    );
};

export default BtnRadio;
```

is there someone who can point me to the right direction i guess that i forgot to bind something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, when you're using non-anonymous functions, `this` gets overridden, and wont refer to the component anymore. Since you're already using [class properties](https://codeburst.io/use-class-properties-to-clean-up-your-classes-and-react-components-93185879f688), the simple fix, is to keep using the arrow functions, to keep `this` referencing the component:

```
onRadioBtnClick = (rSelected) => {
    this.setState({ 
        rSelected:rSelected 
    });
}
```

See #5 in [this medium article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56), which explains different ways of binding `this` to keep it referencing the component.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <BtnToggle onRadioBtnClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick()} active={this.state.rSelected}/>
```

Arrow function for the rescue.

Comment: The OP is already using class properties (See his state), so there is little reason not to continue using class properties, to avoid the performance downfalls of attaching an anonymous function to each component. See [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You should bind the functions your passing like so:

```
class parent extends Component {

    state = {
        rSelected: true,
    }

    onRadioBtnClick(rSelected) {
        this.setState({ 
            rSelected:rSelected 
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (

            <div>
                <BtnToggle onRadioBtnClick={this.onRadioBtnClick.bind(this)} active={this.state.rSelected}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

alternatively, you can bind the functions before passing them in the constructor:

```
class parent extends Component {

    state = {
        rSelected: true,
    }

    constructor() {
        super()

        this.onRadioBtnClick = this.onRadioBtnClick.bind(this)
    }

    onRadioBtnClick(rSelected) {
        this.setState({ 
            rSelected:rSelected 
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (

            <div>
                <BtnToggle onRadioBtnClick={this.onRadioBtnClick} active={this.state.rSelected}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @ŁukaszBlaszyński FYI: what you're suggesting it's not even in ES yet, it's proposal. Not sure why this answer gets downvotes. While arrow functions are more elegant, this answer is "a little bit more correct".

Comment: @Solo The main reason being, OP has already demonstrated that he's using class properties already. There's no reason to add a constructor to this component (Thus complicating things, especially if props are being passed to this component.)

Comment: @FrankerZ I'm sorry, could you link to some documentation or care to elaborate? I don't understand how it complicates things. Thanks!

Comment: @Smarticles101 Doesn't complicate, it's just more annoying and easier to forget. But you didn't deserve these downvotes.

Comment: @Solo okay so it's just a matter of personal preference then, thanks

Comment: @Smarticles101 So for simplistic terms: If you add a constructor, you need to make sure that you're passing the arguments back up to the `super()` function. For example, if the user calls this function with `<parent id="test" />`, with the current code, OP can't access `this.props.id`, because you need to modify the constructor: `constuctor(props) { super(props); bind...`. [This article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) gives a nice demonstration of all the approaches to preserve `this`.

Comment: @Solo Isn't more annoying and easier to forget, the definition of complicate?